# Avoiding duplicate code in constructors

Tags: java, constructor

I have Java code that looks something like this:

```
public class Animal {
    Animal(String name) {
    // some code
    }
}
```

And a subclass like this:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    Dog(String name) {
    // SAME code as Animal constructor
    }
}
```

The only difference between Dog and the Animal is that Dog has some methods that override the superclass. Their constructors have exactly the same code. How can I avoid this duplicated code? I know that an object can't inherit constructors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the constructors are the same you don't need to it in `Dog`. You have access to the `Animal` constructor from `Dog` by calling `super(name);`.

```
public class Animal {
    Animal(String name) {
    // some code
    }
}
```

And in Dog:

```
public class Dog {
    Dog(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that a call to a superclass' constructor must be the first line in your constructor. But after you have called `super(name)` you can go on and do other Dog-specific code.

For example:

```
public class Dog {
    Dog(String name) {
        // You can't put any code here
        super(name);
        // But you can put other code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can delegate to the super constructor:

```
Dog(String name) {
    super(name);
}
```

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html.

Comment: Haha.  I was just about to post exactly this, but SO prevented me because you were faster.  ;)

Comment: Won't that make my Dog object an Animal object?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is right.  Your `Dog` object is an `Animal` object, regardless of whether you call the super constructor.  For example, if you have `class Dog`, `class Cat`, and `class Fish`, which all extend `class Animal`, they can all be put into the same `Animal` array.

Comment: Note that it's impossible to NOT call the superclass constructor. If you don't call another constructor explicitly, the compiler will insert an implicit call to the no-argument super constructor at the top of your constructor.